# PHP add parameters to shutdown function

Tags: php, function, shutdown

I need to send two parameters to a shutdown function on php. The shutdown function is

```
function shutdown($newfile,$back_file)
{
        if(file_exists("../Content/8/$newfile")){
            unlink("../Content/8/$newfile");
        }
        if(file_exists("../Content/8/$back_file")){
            unlink("../Content/8/$back_file");
        }
    echo "Script executed with success $back_file", PHP_EOL;
}
```

As far as I know is, I can declare and register the function as below :

```
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
```

Is there a way that I can send those two parameters to the function?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you should add two parameters in `register_shutdown_function` like this:

```
register_shutdown_function('shutdown', $newFile, $previousFile);
```